# Cassandra failure detection mechanism

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra has gossiper implementation(class org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper) as well as implementation of 'The Phi Accrual Failure Detector'(class org.apache.cassandra.gms.FailureDetector).

As far as I know, both are mechanisms for failure detection. So which one of these is exactly used for detecting node failures by Cassandra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2 work hand-in-hand.

The `FailureDetector` uses the last gossip heartbeat to calculate the elapsed interval in order to decide whether a node has failed and mark it as down. Cheers!